# Search and replace string, but retain some characters

Tags: awk, sed

I'm working with a large CSV file and I need to do some search & replace within the file.

There are random rows that contain text such as this:

```
![](image.png)
```

I need to replace this text with:

```
!image.png!
```

The text in the middle, `image.png` in this example, needs to be retained exactly and it will not always be `image.png`. The string can be on its own line or can be part of a line of unrelated text. The encapsulating characters `![](` and `)` are always the same.  There are other instances of `!`, `[`, `]`, `(` and `)` that cannot be changed. Any advice?

Comment: You need to google "capture group" and/or "backreference" for sed. This is a core function of sed. Here is one example of a short tutorial: https://riptutorial.com/sed/example/8893/backreference.

Comment: don't make readers guess as to what your problematic data looks like. Edit your  to include samples of data that should be modified and those that shouldn't. It will help if you include other sample data to give context. Good luck.

Comment: Why not just `sed 's/!\[\](\([^)]*\))/!\1!/g'`?

Comment: Thanks @oguzismail That's what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

`myfile.txt` contains:

```
oneline
![](image.png)
other line
![](image2.png)
another line
Reference this image ![](image.png) to see what I mean.
Check out this Word Doc ![](file.docx)
another line
```

With this awk program:

```
 gawk '{ match($0, /!\[\]\(([a-z0-9_]+.[a-z]+)/, arr); if(arr[1] != "") print "!"arr[1]"!" }' myfile.txt
```

You'll get this output:

```
!image.png!
!image2.png!
!another.png!
!image.png!
!file.docx!
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This is along the lines of what I was thinking, however, I didn't make the details of the source file clear enough. The strings that need to change are almost never at the beginning of a line. They are randomly through the line in some place. Something like: `Reference this image ![](image.png) to see what I mean.` Or `Check out this Word Doc ![](file.docx)`

Comment: It would help if you post a part of your file; this allows me to consider the variants. Please post a part of your file.

Comment: `02-10-2018 10:34;began;This bug occurs now with a deck with a 100 run AB CDE. For a target (see attached image) with all data at the outlier step are "No Value". it is still listed as OK and not failed. See attached deck AB_12345.zip. Postpone to 8.0. ![](image.png)","03-10-2018 07:59;username3;QA-failed per Bill's request.","08-02-2019 12:05;username2;Fixed in branch.","11-02-2019 13:30;username4; QA Failed Target given OK even when all runs under it have "No Value"","15-05-2019 12:51;username1;Seems to be fixed now.\n\nValidated on RHEL7 and Win10.\n\nBuild 4.010(2018-07-19)",,,,,,,`

Comment: The "image.png" portion of the ![](image.png) string does not always have a png file extension.

Comment: Now, you can review the answer.